# How to pass data in install data intent and get it installed Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, android-intent

Hi I am looking a way to send any data in install intent & get this data in install/replace broadcast reciever.

I am doing install intent like below

```
Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setDataAndType(
                    Uri.parse("file:///" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test.apk"), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
promptInstall.putExtra("data", "value");
startActivity(promptInstall);
```

In Install Broadcast Receiver.

```
public class NewPackageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("DEBUG"," test for application install/uninstall");
    }

}
```

### Question

I sent `promptInstall.putExtra("data", "value");` in install intent then How I can get this data value in the install broadcast receiver.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The extra data you add to your install Intent is not included in the PACKAGE_ADDED Intent sent by the system when a package was added.

Answer (score 0):

What i did to achieved this is simply by creating a `public` method in the `BroadcastReceiver`, example :

```
public static void setAlarms(Context context)
```

And then i called that method in the `actvitiy` directly, and call it in the `onReceive` :

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    setAlarms(context);
}
```

Comment: `And then i called that method in the actvitiy directly` -- Here what you called ? I want to have that passed data once system broadcast the event that apk has been installed so I can not call any method of receiver direct because we dont know at till point of time that whether app has installed or not so lets this do all receiver.